# How should I deallocate the memory of an object created without using the "new" keyword?

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management

If I create an object without using the "new" keyword, how should I free its memory?

Example:

```
#include "PixelPlane.h"

int main(void)
{
     PixelPlane pixel_plane(960, 540, "TITLE");
     //How should the memory of this object be freed?
}
```

Comment: It happens automatically when the life-time of the variable `pixel_plane` ends, which happens when the scope ends. That leads to the objects destruction and the memory being released (in an implementation-defined manner).

Comment: If the object has a proper destructor, you don't need to. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036394/how-do-i-call-the-classs-destructor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling delete on variable allocated on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441831/calling-delete-on-variable-allocated-on-the-stack)

Comment: Why the vote down? The question is properly presented. You should not vote people down just because you know the answer, they do not, and you think it is elementary. **Every** student of C++ needs to learn the answer to this, so it is useful information for many people.

Comment: Is the memory automatically freed if `pixel_plane` is defined globally?

Comment: @SuperSim135 Yes, when the process terminates.

Comment: @SuperSim135: That's a different question.

Comment: Handy reading: [Storage class specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) All of this is informative, but the section on Storage Duration is most relevant.

Answer (score 3):

`pixel_plane` is a variable with automatic storage duration (i.e. a normal local variable).

It will be freed when execution of the enclosing scope ends (i.e. when the function returns).

---

This is an example of a local variable that doesn't have automatic storage duration.

```
void my_function()
{
    static PixelPlane pixel_plane(960, 540, "TITLE");
    // pixel_plane has static storage duration - it is not freed until the program exits.
    // Also, it's only allocated once.
}
```

---

This is an example of an enclosing scope that is not a function:

```
int main(void)
{
    PixelPlane outer_pixel_plane(960, 540, "TITLE");

    {
        PixelPlane inner_pixel_plane(960, 540, "TITLE");
    } // inner_pixel_plane freed here

    // other code could go here before the end of the function

} // outer_pixel_plane freed here
```

Comment: Storage is freed when execution of the associated block ends, not when scope ends. Scope does not have any end in time, just in place. Scope is **where** in source code identifiers are visible. Storage duration or lifetime is **when** during program execution objects exist. An automatic object ceases to exist when execution of its associated block ends (and not merely when program control temporarily leaves the block, as when a subroutine is called).